# this.addChild is not a function cocos2d-js

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I'm new in cocos2d-js, and I wanna simplify my code, but I have problem here here the code

```
var GameLayerEasy = cc.Layer.extend({

ctor:function () {
    // 1. super init first
    this._super();

    this.addBG4();
},

addBG4: function(){
    var size = cc.director.getWinSize();
    var sprite = new cc.Sprite.create(res.BG4_png);
    sprite.setPosition(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    this.addChild(sprite, 0);
}
});
```

it's okay with this code, but I have many `GameLayer` instances and using same `addBG4`, it's not efficient if I type `addBG4` function again each `GameLayer` so I'm trying change the code like this

```
var GameLayerEasy = cc.Layer.extend({
ctor:function () {
    // 1. super init first
    this._super();

    addBG4();
},
});

function addBG4(){
    var size = cc.director.getWinSize();
    var sprite = new cc.Sprite.create(res.BG4_png);
    sprite.setPosition(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    this.addChild(sprite,0);
}
```

but I got this error `this.addChild is not a function`
can someone help me with the code, and please tell me what's wrong with this, thank you

Comment: This is a JavaScript question only. Nothing cocos-related. In the first example 'this' stands for the GameLayerEasy instance, while in the second "this" is global, i.e. window object.

Comment: @РоманГуйван thanks for explanation. but I'm still confuse about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure it now,
I'm trying like this and my code is working

```
var GameLayerEasy = cc.Layer.extend({
    ctor:function () {
    this._super();

    addBG4(this);
},
});

function addBG4(that){
    var size = cc.director.getWinSize();
    var sprite = new cc.Sprite.create(res.BG4_png);
    sprite.setPosition(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    that.addChild(sprite,0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
  function addBG4(){
    var size = cc.director.getWinSize();
    var sprite = new cc.Sprite(res.BG4_png);
    sprite.setPosition(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    this.addChild(sprite,0);
  }
```

Comment: thanks for help, I'm trying change my code with your suggestion, but I'm still got error `sprite is not a constructor`

Comment: Because it's either new cc.Sprite(res.BG4_png); or cc.Sprite.create(...) I've submitted an edit already. also don't need that 'new' portion in the addChild call and last of all - this won't fix the scoping issue.

Comment: @РоманГуйван still got error `this.addChild is not a function`, btw thanks i figure it now.